# Tengo un problemas con el ordenamiento mergesort en javascript

Tags: javascript

Ordena bien pero cuando agrego comas(,) se rompe y ya busque cambiar e incluso hice que ordenara letras pero no comprendo cual puede ser el error, ordena bien solo si ingresas lo valores a ordenar desde el código es decir dentro del `javascript` pero cuando me lo da a través del input no simplemente ordena números del 1 al 9 y sin comas cuando agrego comas solo me los separa(si agrego 10,11,12 me lo ordena así:0,1,1,1,1,2) es decir me los separa realmente no veo el error alguien me puede ayudar?

```js
var ingresar = null;

function sub()
{
  ingresar = document.getElementsByName("ingresar")[0].value;

};

function mergeSort (array) 
{
    if (array.length === 1)
    {
       return array;
    }

   var longitud = Math.floor(array.length / 2) //obtiene e lelemento central de la matriz redondeado hacia abajo
   var derecha = array.slice(0, longitud) // elementos en el lado izquierdo
   var izquierda = array.slice(longitud)  // elementos en el lado derecho
  
   return merge(mergeSort(izquierda), mergeSort(derecha));
}

function merge  (izquierda, derecha)
{
  var result = [];
  var il = ir = 0;

  while (il < izquierda.length && ir < derecha.length) 
  {
    //Si invierto el menor que, del if se ordena de mayor a menor :v
    if (izquierda[il] < derecha[ir]) 
    {
      result.push(izquierda[il])
      il++
    } 
    else
    {
      result.push(derecha[ir])
      ir++
    }
  }
     
  return [...result,...izquierda.slice(il),...derecha.slice(ir)];
}
  
var array = (ingresar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>b</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>ingresar numeros</h2>
    <form name="form"  method="get">
        <input type="text" name="ingresar" id="ingresar" placeholder="ingresa numeros">
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar información"> 
    </form>
      
    <output type="text" id="salida"></output>
        
    <button 
          onclick="sub()
          document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML=mergeSort(ingresar)">Prueba
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas hacer tu ordenamiento usando Arrays y no cadenas.  Puedes obtener un array utilizando `split()` asi:

```js
var ingresar = null;

function sub()
{
  ingresar = document.getElementsByName("ingresar")[0].value.split(",");

};

function mergeSort (array) 
{        
    if (array.length === 1)
    {
       return array;
    }

   var longitud = Math.floor(array.length / 2) //obtiene e lelemento central de la matriz redondeado hacia abajo
   var derecha = array.slice(0, longitud) // elementos en el lado izquierdo
   var izquierda = array.slice(longitud)  // elementos en el lado derecho
  
   return merge(mergeSort(izquierda), mergeSort(derecha));
}

function merge  (izquierda, derecha)
{
  var result = [];
  var il = ir = 0;

  while (il < izquierda.length && ir < derecha.length) 
  {
    //Si invierto el menor que, del if se ordena de mayor a menor :v
    if (izquierda[il] < derecha[ir]) 
    {
      result.push(izquierda[il])
      il++
    } 
    else
    {
      result.push(derecha[ir])
      ir++
    }
  }
     
  return [...result,...izquierda.slice(il),...derecha.slice(ir)];
}
  
var array = (ingresar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>b</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>ingresar numeros</h2>
    <form name="form"  method="get">
        <input type="text" name="ingresar" id="ingresar" placeholder="ingresa numeros">
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar información"> 
    </form>
      
    <output type="text" id="salida"></output>
        
    <button 
          onclick="sub()
          document.getElementById('salida').innerHTML=mergeSort(ingresar)">Prueba
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hola yo de nuevo, aunque en problema de la (,)esta resuelto sigue sin ordenarme los números prueba ejecutar el codigo con el split y agrega numeros desordenados del 1 al 15 por ejemplo. aunque ya encontre el error vera en el split ay que agragarle split.(",").map(Number).